# How to anti-sort data using R

Tags: r, sorting

I'm not sure how to name it but if I have a list of values like:

```
set.seed(2084)
vals = round(runif(12, 1, 3))
```

[1] 2 3 2 2 1 1 3 2 1 2 2 2

and I sort it I have:

[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3

But I want to get something like alternate sorting (take 1-2-3 and repeat):

1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 2 2 2 2

But the problem is there's 7 twos and they are trailing the list instead of being alternated between other values. I'd rather expect to get something like:

1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 3

or

1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2

How can I index it to get the most uniformly distributed values of this "growing and cutting" order?

To give some view at my idea. From the set of N unique values (here 3) we need to distribute each of them to be as far as possible from one another (and from boundaries of this vector). So while 1, and 10 slots we have, we can put ones like in this pattern:

= 1 = = = 1 = = = 1

or

= = 1 = = 1 = = 1 =

It's correct unless other numbers have appropriate positions in this list. We can add threes:

= 3 1 = = 1 = 3 1 =

Now, we have only twos to fill in. They won't have ideal positions. I think it'd be best to start with the number with the most abundant values.

I wanted to be clear and describe some algorithm but I feel it's vice-versa effect.

**# EDIT #**
I guess for larger datasets the topic could stand "how to uniformly distribute values in a given vector using R". Maybe this could be a safe exit from this situation if it's rally leads to misunderstanding. But Here I don't want to have 2 numbers besides while 5 slots are available.

For `1 2 2 3 4` there's an alternative as for example `1 2 3 4 2`.

**EDIT 2**

I've found a function for 2 values - it's semi-solution but the idea is working. I think it's about to be iterative for more than 2 values, but maybe I'm wrong.

It's not very elegant

```
antisort <- function(vals) {
  l = length(unique(vals))
  mx = names(which.max(table(vals)))
  mn = names(which.min(table(vals)))
  mxn = max(table(vals))
  indx = round(seq(from = 1, to = length(vals), length.out = mxn))
  vec = NULL
  for (i in indx) {
    vec[i] <- mx
  }
  vec[which(is.na(vec))] <- mn
  return(vec)
}
```

data:

```
set.seed(2201)
vals = round(runif(12, 1, 2))
```

run:

```
antisort(vals)
```

Result (no matter it's stringed)

"2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2"

Comment: I think you need to be more clear or provide a few additional examples. For instance, why `1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 3` and not `1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2` or `1 2 2 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3`?

Comment: Are you looking for a "right" answer? Why `1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 3` instead of `1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2`? Or `1 2 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 3`? Or are any of those fine, you don't care which one? What if your starting sequence was `1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3`?

Comment: All above are fine because each value is distrubuted possible uniformly.

Comment: Your logic of knowing where to put the extra 2s is certainly confusing. What is the mathematic (ordering) principle behind *"alternated between other values"*?

Comment: @r2evans I mean, each value should be uniformly distributed - without tendency to be on the beginning nor end of the vector.

Comment: And what determines the number of "restarts" - the number of times the sequence is allowed to decrease? Do they all need to start with the lowest value? If your input was `1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4` would that be a good result as-is, or would you want `1 2 2 3 3 4 2 2 3 3 4 2 2 3 3`? Or something else.

Comment: @Gregor The ordering is not important - it can be easily reversed if needed. Your example with 4 is correct, s.o you get the idea

Comment: A random order is uniformly distributed - your examples are clearly not. The lowest value has probability 1 of being the first value and 0 of being the last. I think you need to work through defining better what you mean before this is ready to be a good question. I suggest you add several examples to your question of possible inputs and acceptable outputs & try to articulate better any rules you can identify. For now, I'm voting to close as "unclear".

Comment: Both my examples with 4 are correct? Or just 1?

Comment: This second one, because first one is just sorted list in asc. order.

Comment: But I don't see what's wrong with "just sorted in asc. order". If the input is `1 2 3 4`, can you enumerate all possible outputs that are acceptable? What if the input is `1 2 2 3 4`?

Comment: For `1 2 2 3 4` there are twos which could be separated by some values. Please read my edits.

Comment: I believe what OP wants is to order the values so that they _look_ random, without _actually_ being random. This is actually a done thing in some places, eg in videogames, people will often see patterns in randomly distributed numbers that aren't really there. To deal with this, the developers tweak the numbers so that eg, long strings of repeats don't happen and other such tricks.

Comment: Instead of one example of acceptable ouptut for given inputs, I think it would be really helpful to try to clarify **all** acceptable outputs for a given input. I have *some* sense of what you want, but I can't generalize it and asking you about possibilities one-case-at-a-time isn't getting us anywhere fast. I still have no idea what you mean when you say "*The ordering is not important - it can be easily reversed if needed*". Let's take the `1 2 2 3 4` example. Is `1 2 3 2 4` good? Is `1 2 3 4 2` better? What about `2 1 3 4 2` for maximum separation of the 2s?...

Comment: Do we need ascending subsequences? What about `4 2 3 2 1`, for descending? Or neither ascending nor descending, `3 2 1 2 4`? Can we say as a rule that any result with the 2's next to each other is bad? There are 36 possibilities without the 2's together, can you classify them all as good or bad? You can list them with `x = unique(apply(RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4), m = 5), 1, paste, collapse = ""));
x = x[!grepl("22", x)]; x`

Comment: And, going back to your first example with the 7 twos, if you want to avoid having things next to each other, why is `1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 3` preferable to `2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 2` where only 2 2s touch? (Or is it preferable?).

Comment: When you talk about a *"growing and cutting"*, can you define grow and cut? I *think* you mean little subsequences that are in ascending order (*grow*), and then when there is a decrease you call it a *cut*. If I'm right, do you want to penalize the number of "cuts"? Do you want to penalize short subsequences (lengths of each "grow")? `2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 2` has lots of cuts (5 places where there is a descending order), but only 1 adjacent pair. `1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 3` Has 2 cuts, but 3 adjacent pairs. The sorted version `1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3` has 0 cuts and 9 adjacent pairs...

Comment: But maybe more than adjacency matters? You talk about values being *"as far as possible from one another"*, which suggests that you're worried about more than adjacency, and I don't understand how. Then you add *"and from boundaries of this vector"*, which I find really confusing - the vector always has 2 boundaries, and there will always be values next to them. Is it worse to have repeated values at the boundaries? How much worse is `* 2 * 2 *`  than `2 * * * 2` or `* 2 * * 2`?

Answer (score 0):

One of these may be what you were after:

```
rep_len(unique(vals), length(vals))
```

or

```
rep_len(sort(unique(vals)), length(vals))
```

Comment: This changes the frequencies. Compare `table(vals)` (3 `1`s, 7 `2`s, and 2 `3`s in OPs input) to a `table()` of your results--4 of each.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible heuristic approach:

```
set.seed(2084)
maxn <- 3
vals = round(runif(12, 1, maxn)) #integral values

#result vector
v <- rep(NA_character_, length(vals))

#tabulate frequencies and sort in descending order
lens <- sort(table(vals), decreasing=TRUE)

#going through each distinct integral values, starting with the longest one
for (x in names(lens)) {
    #cut the result vector into roughly lens[x] number of parts
    idx <- cut(seq_along(v), breaks=lens[x])

    #fill the first NA with the current integral value
    split(v, idx) <- lapply(split(v, idx), function(subv) {
        subv[which(is.na(subv))[1L]] <- x
        subv
    })
}

#split the vector into maxn number of parts and sort each group
#the hardest part is probably how many parts to split into, which is defaulted
#to maximum of integral values in the original vector
lapply(split(v, cut(seq_along(v), breaks=maxn, labels=1L:maxn)), sort)
```

output:

```
$`1`
[1] "1" "2" "2" "3"

$`2`
[1] "1" "2" "2" "2"

$`3`
[1] "1" "2" "2" "3"
```

Relevant link: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29709/algorithm-to-distribute-items-evenly